# Memory leak on GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

We are having this error and the JSP page becomes blank (white):

> Jan 9, 2013 7:30:39 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   clearThreadLocalMap SEVERE: The web application [/MyWebApp] created a
>   ThreadLocal with key of type [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.DateTime$1]
>   (value [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.DateTime$1@48a47]) and a value of
>   type [java.util.GregorianCalendar] (value
>   [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1357531128420,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Australia/Sydney",offset=36000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=142,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Australia/Sydney,offset=36000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=9,startDay=1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=1,endMode=3,endMonth=3,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=1]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=2,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=7,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=14,MINUTE=58,SECOND=48,MILLISECOND=420,ZONE_OFFSET=36000000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is
>   very likely to create a memory leak.

Suggested solutions are:

- use new instances for each time a `Calendar` is needed or
- check whether some hook in `ResultSet.close` is sufficient for calling `ThreadLocal.remove()`

However, in our case we need to reproduce the error, so it is possible to test the fix, without waiting indefinitely for the error to happen again.

Comment: ermm ... so whats your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given message is not the cause of your problem.

Tomcat is only informing that there could be a memory leak (which must not be true). This error occurs during shutdown every time (try it).

Comment: ...but what is the cause of the blank JSP page I get? After tomcat reload the blank JSP page is not blank anymore and shows up properly?

Comment: @xybrek The blank page is dsplayed because the web application is not running anymore.

Comment: Question is, why is it not running anymore? When no one stopped the tomcat service?

Comment: @xybrek This is a question that nobody here can answer you.

Comment: Right, what I mean is that: You are saying that the blank page we encounter is not cause by memory leak / calendar static access ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer given by @Uwe Plonus I can say that this happens when application is stopped. So, unless you stop and start your application multiple times without restarting your tomcat this is not so interesting. If this happens when tomcat is closing applications during its shutdown this memory leak is irrelevant: the tomcat itself will die in a moment.

Comment: what do you mean with "die in a moment"? also why we are getting blank page, then after tomcat reload it is OK... ?